# Manipulate image placeholder while image source is being loaded or broken using CSS

Tags: css, image, placeholder

Before image gets loaded it displays an image placeholder with a border, that can't be removed. So I would like to hide or replace default image placeholder.

I'm after a CSS-only solution avoiding Javascript code.

My current CSS looks like this:

```
img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
    border-radius: 25px;

    -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
    -moz-background-clip: border-box;
    background-clip: border-box;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/litera/DDEcB/) where first image is broken and its placeholder is visible and therefore annoying because it distorts original image border.

### What I tried

I've tried the `content` trick to remove placeholder altogether, but that also removes the actual image if it's not broken and should be displayed.

```
display: inline-block;
content: "";
```

**Anybody has a solution to this?**

Answer (score 1):

@maak already replied the same answer below

for FF

`-moz-force-broken-image-icon: <integer>;`

is an extended CSS property.

Examples

```
img {
  -moz-force-broken-image-icon: 1;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}

<img src='/broken/image/link.png' alt='Broken image link'>
```

[Read Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-force-broken-image-icon)

For other browsers I am not sure about such property, but a jquery although you want to avoid it

```
// Replace source
$('img').error(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'missing.png');
});

// Or, hide them
$("img").error(function(){
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: On error handling is not really an option. Not because it's javascript, but because it executes to late in the process. When page loads, browser displays image placeholders and then loads images. After loading fails, onerror handler gets executed. A better way would be a combination of my *trick* and on load handler that would remove the CSS class with appropriate settings so the image would get displayed...

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, there is no CSS-only solution to this.
CSS cannot determine between a loaded and unloaded images.

BUT the browsers do can.

Firefox for example has something you can [give a try](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-force-broken-image-icon).
But that's too elaborated for now…

I modified your fiddle and inserted

```
alt=""
```

to your images.

In Firefox the broken image disappeared, since the browser now renders the alt-text.

bye:maak.

Answer (score 0):

provide image through background-image: url(srctoimg); than src='srctoimg'

```
<img style='background-image: url(srctoimg);'>
img{ 
display: block;
background: white;
content: "";
background-size: 100%;
text-indent: -999px
}
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skcppb53/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps just hide it?

```
img{
  ::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
  ::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* firefox 19+ */
  :-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* ie */
  input:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; }
}
```